# Add custom error handler at beginning of modules section in web.config (not manually)

Tags: 2010, web-config, http-module, spwebconfigmodification, error-handling

Is there a way to put an error handler HTTPModule at the beginning of the modules section in web.config without doing this manually?

I've tried the supplemental web.config approach like this:

```
  <add path="configuration/system.webServer/modules" id="{125A654F-9220-42F0-A97A-1746252468DE}">
    <add name="CustomErrorHandler" type="com.handlers.CustomErrorHandler, Assemblyname, Version=4.5.6.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3450345789" />
  </add>
```

The problem is that the custom error handler has to be placed before the standard handler. If you don't, sharepoint handles the exception itself and delivers the standard exception page.

Expected:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="CustomErrorHandler" type="com.handlers.CustomErrorHandler, Assemblyname, Version=4.5.6.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3450345789" />
  <remove name="FileAuthorization" />
  <remove name="Profile" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="SPRequestModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="SharePoint14Module" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="StateServiceModule" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.StateModule, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add name="RSRedirectModule" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Soap.RSRedirectModule, RSSharePointSoapProxy, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  <add name="PublishingHttpModule" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingHttpModule, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
</modules>
```

Result by supplemental approach:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FileAuthorization" />
  <remove name="Profile" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="SPRequestModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="SharePoint14Module" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="StateServiceModule" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.StateModule, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add name="RSRedirectModule" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Soap.RSRedirectModule, RSSharePointSoapProxy, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  <add name="PublishingHttpModule" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingHttpModule, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add name="CustomErrorHandler" type="com.handlers.CustomErrorHandler, Assemblyname, Version=4.5.6.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3450345789" />
</modules>
```

Like this thread says (confiremd by MS Developer) there is no way to control the order of nodes when working with SPWebConfigModification:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/154a09de-d9fc-4622-a397-589a3c1a87e5/

Adding the web.config entry manually is no option.

Is there really no other way?

Comment: Could you please share the code of HttpModule, and how are you handling the request? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up with a different approach for my custom error pages.

Because it is not possible to control the order of elements in web.config programmatically (which sucks so much!) and editing manually is no option, I gave up the approach with a HttpModule and manipulating web.config.

Instead I wrote a web application scoped feature receiver like described here:
http://todd-carter.com/post/2010/04/07/An-Expected-Error-Has-Occurred.aspx
to set a custom error page for the application (which handles exceptions). The custom error page has a control which renders a custom message for the user and logs the exception.

Additionally I added a custom 404.html file to the solution in the mapped LAYOUTS\1033 folder and registered that file for the application in the same feature receiver (see code below). The 404.html does a redirect to a .aspx-File. The aspx has a control which renders the content internationalized. You can also just set the static html for 404 errors. The reason for the redirect was internationalization.

One additional pitfall with the .html file and non-IE-browsers was for me the problem described here (because I copied the standard SP 404.html for a starting point):

http://andreasglaser.net/post/2009/03/15/SharePoint-and-custom-404-Page-Not-Found-and-UTF-8-issue-with-Firefox.aspx

Code goes here:

```
private const string CustomErrorPage = "/_layouts/CustomError.aspx";

public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;

  if (webApp != null)
  {
    if (!webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.Error, CustomErrorPage))
    {
      throw new ApplicationException("Cannot create the new error page mapping.");
    }
  }

  webApp.FileNotFoundPage = "Custom404.html";
  webApp.Update(true);
}

public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;

  if (!webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.Error, null))
  {
    throw new ApplicationException("Cannot reset the default error page mapping.");
  }
  webApp.FileNotFoundPage = String.Empty;
  webApp.Update(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work as expected then I would recommend you to use [Xpath together with SPWebModifications](http://stephenkaye.blogspot.se/2008/07/master-webconfigmodifications.html) to define the order.

**Update**

I just tested it out my solution together with XPath solution and it's not behaving as expected. It seems that there is **no way** of controlling the order of entries. Thanks Per for his input!

**Update 2**

Could you please try using `HttpApplication` instead of `HttpContext` because `HttpApplication` defines the methods, properties, and events common to all application objects within an ASP.NET application. [See more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error%28v=vs.90%29)

> Usage

```
 HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
```

Comment: The requirement in the question was to put the module at the begining of to `<Modules>` section which you can't do with SPWebConfigModifications

Comment: I've just tested you code and it puts MyModuleName as the LAST entry in modules

Comment: They seems to be added alphabetically but after all the standard entries. And as the link in the question confirms there is no way of controlling it

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it out myself with XPath and it's not behaving as expected. It seems there is no way of controlling the order.

Comment: That's really poor. So the only solution is to edit the web.config manually...

Comment: Why you need a specific order? Could you please share the insight?

Comment: here's the citation from my question above: "The problem is that the custom error handler has to be placed before the standard handlers. If you don't, sharepoint handles the exception itself and delivers the standard exception page."

Comment: Could you please share the code of HttpModule, and how are you handling the request?

Comment: Added the Module code in my question. If I debug, the code, HandleError is executed, but sharepoint delivers the standard exception page. However, if the module is placed as first module in web.config it works fine

Comment: See my updated (Update 2) response

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I gave up the custom error handling httpModule approach. Didn't have the time to test your last update. But I read it a dozen times (and tested it ) that it has to be the first module in web.config. And that is not possible neither with SPWebModifications nor with the supplemental web.config approach. See my solution in my answer below