# “The resource cannot be found.” error 404 when there is a “dot” at the end of the url in sharepoint

Tags: 2010, url, iis, 404, url-rewriting

I'm trying to handle “The resource cannot be found.” error 404 when there is a dot at the end of url in sharepoint 2010 site.

I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-ur , this link is talking about

`<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` which is supported only in .Net 4.0 but sharepoint 2010 is working with .Net 3.5 CLR 2.0 I tried also handling `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` in global.asax but it didn't work  , I tried also ' IIS URL Rewriting Module 2.0. ' but I don't know how to use it correctly is it an inbound rule or outbound rule ? .

any help please , Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i presume from the reply that you want a custom 404 page? there are two methods. One is generic:

> To configure SharePoint Foundation server or SharePoint Server 2010 to
>   point to a custom 404 error Web page, follow these steps.
>
> **1**.Log on to the computer that is running SharePoint Server 2010 by using an account that has administrative permissions.
>
> **2**.In Windows Explorer, locate the following folder:
>
> %systemdrive% \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\LangID
>
> Notes
>
> • In this path, %systemdrive% represents the actual drive name of the
>   drive on which the operating system is installed.
>
> • In this path, LangID represents the actual language ID of the
>   language that you use. For example, 1033 is the language ID for U.S.
>   English.
>
> **3**.Create the custom HTML file:
>
> a.On the computer that is running SharePoint Server 2010, copy the
>   Sps404.html file to a temporary folder.  b.Rename the Sps404.html
>   file. For example, give the file the following name:
>
> Custom404.html c.Modify the Custom404.html file to suit your needs for
>   a custom 404 error message using an HTML editor.
>
> **4**.Copy the Custom404.html file to the %systemdrive% \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\LangID folder.
>
> **5**.Run the following PowerShell commands from the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell: $webapp =Get-SPWebApplication
>   http://: $webapp.FileNotFoundPage = "Custom404.html"
>   $webapp.update()
>
> Verify that the property is set by running the following command:
>
> (Get-SPWebApplication http://:).FileNotFoundPage

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941329

if you want somthing that would handle a specific error, than that is different and will require some programming.

[Add custom error handler at beginning of modules section in web.config (not manually)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37736/add-custom-error-handler-at-beginning-of-modules-section-in-web-config-not-manu)

the above method is what iv done (similar) to handle different types of errors and i attached it to a feature to add and remove customisation when i want :)

**EDIT**

due to a link it refers within the second version that he referes to as the solution I have taken the oppertunity to save the content, this from google cache.

> An Expected Error Has Occurred 1 Reply  There is not a single sole on
>   this planet which has used SharePoint that has not seen the error
>   message “An Unexpected Error has occurred”. Bold statement, and
>   obviously I don’t have the research to back it up but you must admit
>   its an error allot of folks see from time to time if you spend any
>   time on a SharePoint site – hopefully that will change soon.
>
> With SharePoint 2010 you can now set your own custom error pages. This
>   has been a much asked for feature from allot of my customers and has
>   the potential to offer a much  better user experience. In fact, one
>   which you may choose to vary depending on the role of the user. For
>   example, you may want to provide a very generic error for anonymous
>   users and a much more detailed error of the user happens to be the
>   site collection owner or farm admin.
>
> Its not only the error pages that got all the love here, in fact you
>   can customize the Access Denied, Confirmation, Login, Request Access,
>   Sign-out, and Web Deleted pages. The SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage
>   enumerator is used to pass the page which you wish to override into a
>   call to UpdateMappedPage() along with the path to the custom page. So
>   once set, this page will be used anytime a request is made for the
>   corresponding page. Since this method is part of the SPWebApplication
>   you will note a custom pages are scoped to the web application.
>
> What is really happening here is SharePoint’s Virtual Path Provider
>   (VPP) does a check each time it’s asked to resolve a path to a file
>   and if the current Web Application has a custom page configured it
>   will be served rather than the original error page. This means URLs
>   and code references to these pages will not need to be updated to
>   paths to your custom files because the VPP handles the redirection.
>
> If you choose to remove a custom page you make the same call into
>   UpdateMappedpage passing NULL for the page path and the corresponding
>   enum value for the page you wish to disconnect.
>
> I would highly recommend anyone who deploys an Internet facing
>   SharePoint site override at the very least the error page for at least
>   three reasons:
>
> 1) Own your messaging to the anonymous user, don’t let SharePoint send
>   messages to your users. What is the point of giving them an error they
>   most likely cannot understand, don’t care too, and most likely could
>   not take any corrective action to fix.
>
> 2) Currently there is a bug that will hopefully get fixed before
>   SharePoint 2010  hits RTM which allows anyone to place an error
>   message on the error page, for example on your SharePoint site append
>   this string to your URL:  _layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=ErrorBaby!
>
> 3) There is an opportunity to offer a better user experience, the
>   custom error page might collect additional information and send that
>   along to those interested, you may choose to collect additional
>   information from the user by asking for feedback, or you may offer
>   additional details if the user is privileged enough, based on his or
>   her role to understand what may be going on with the server.
>
> Here is some example code to get you started – this is a custom
>   feature receiver which you might use to hook a custom error page.

```
  [Guid("bf07336a-76d7-4324-8908-74e2771bba49")]
   public class CustomPageMappingsFeatureEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
   {
       const string CustomErrorPage = "/_layouts/CustomPageMappings/Error.aspx";

       public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
       {
           SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
           if (webApp != null)
           {
               if (!webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.Error, CustomErrorPage))
               {
                   throw new ApplicationException("Cannot create the new error page mapping.");
               }
               webApp.Update(true);
           }
       }

       public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
       {
           SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
           if (webApp != null)
           {
               if (!webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.Error, null))
               {
                   throw new ApplicationException("Cannot reset the default error page mapping.");
               }
               webApp.Update(true);
           }
       }
   }
```

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BwmRJQ5_eUUJ:todd-carter.com/post/2010/04/07/an-expected-error-has-occurred/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Answer (score 6):

According to Microsoft:

- You cannot use the period character at the end of a site name, a subsite name, or a site group name.
- You cannot use the period  character at the end of a folder name.
- You cannot use the period character at the end of a file name

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231/en-us

Are you looking for a way to by-pass this directive?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I know that using . character is illegal , I want to handle this issue if user entered a wrong link , I want to redirect him to friendly page , not asp.net 404 error page